# Design/Souce view of JSP in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Build id: 20090621-0832.

When opening a jsp, how to open design, source, design/source view. 
In RAD, weblogic studio by default all jsps open so.

Is is possible to Do in Eclipse? How to Do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Web Page Editor**, otherwise, this is a feature that commercial products charge for.